# document.ready() fires click only once

Tags: jquery

I am trying to figure out reason why the `click()` is executed once when written in `document.ready()` function.

Here is what I did:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('td').click(function(){

        $('#xyz').html($(this).parent().index());  // here div gets filled with current rowIndex
    });

});
```

**When clicked on a table cell the div shows current row index. *But this happens only once, I want it to show this on every click***.

**Here is the link to js.fiddle [Click Me](http://jsfiddle.net/XZtLz/7/)
If any cell of row is Clicked, it executes click only once..**

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a demo on http://www.jsfiddle.net?

Comment: You can't fill same index again which is filled, and also you are filling a div which have a specific id.

Comment: I am a newbie to Jquery. I used "live" too. Maybe I am making some mistake. You can check the fiddle link to get clear idea of what is been done.

Answer (score 0):

try using this:

```
$('td').click(function() {
    $('.xyz',this).html($(this).parent().index());
});​
```

i have used .xyz div class to fill the index because you should give same id more than 1 elements on the page.

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

that click will only work when a page is rendered as you have written onready function.this event does not get triggered until all assets such as images have been completely received

```
$(document).ready(function() {//your code here});
```

and activity of rendering occurs after pageload or refresh.your function will work for once every-time your page gets loaded or refreshed.

Comment: @Codenewbie: Are you loading contents dynamically?

Comment: what comes in `dynamically` here ?